# Разбить строку в определенных позициях

Tags: python, строки

Допустим есть строка `1234567890` и есть массив `[1,4,10]`.Я хочу разбить строку по массиву, то есть я хочу чтобы у меня был массив разбитой строки от 0 до 1, от 1 до 4, от 4 до 10

Answer (score 1):

```
In [175]: s = "1234567890"

In [176]: lst = [1,4,10]

In [177]: res = [s[lst[i-1] if i>0 else 0 : lst[i]] for i in range(len(lst))]
```

---

результат:

```
In [178]: res
Out[178]: ['1', '234', '567890']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '1234567890'
arr = [1,4,10]
sep = [s[:arr[0]]]
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    sep.append(s[arr[i]:arr[i+1]])
print(sep)
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант списковым включением:

```
s = '1234567890'
stops = [1, 4, 10]

result = [s[slice(*sl)] for sl in zip([None] + stops, stops)]
print(result)  # -> ['1', '234', '567890']
```

В ленивом виде:

```
from itertools import starmap

m = map(s.__getitem__, starmap(slice, zip([None] + stops, stops)))
print(*m)  # -> 1 234 567890
```